# How do dynamically define table column names so naming updates propagate through all references

Tags: mysql

Consider the following mock code.

```sql
-- create tables
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE movies (
movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE movie_user (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);



-- insert some values
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F');
INSERT INTO movies VALUES (1, 'ShowABC');
INSERT INTO movies VALUES (2, 'Show123');
INSERT INTO movie_user VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO movie_user VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO movie_user VALUES (3, 2, 2);

-- fetch some values
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM movies;
SELECT * FROM movie_user;
```

There's a problem with this.

Suppose I wish to change the name of `user_id` to `user_identification`. That's an issue because then I have to update this manually in the other table `movie_user`. If I had 30 tables like this which referenced `user_id`, that would mean there would be a large chance for mistakes.

I wish to centralize this so that way I only have one reference to the column names so that, when I update them at that one centralized location, the names of the columns will update for all the tables.

How do I do this?

#### Stuff I've tried

I tried

`SET @user_id = 'user_id';`

and then intended to replace `user_id` with `@user_id` throughout the code, but that didn't work because I got the following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@user_id INTEGER' at line 1
```

which I gather means

> In standard SQL, you cannot use variables to define column names in a
> CREATE TABLE statement. The syntax for defining a column name requires
> a column name to be specified as an identifier, which is a fixed
> string literal that does not vary during execution.
>
> The reason for this is that column names are part of the table schema,
> which is determined at the time the table is created. The schema
> specifies the structure of the table, including the names and data
> types of its columns. Since the schema is fixed at creation time, it
> cannot be changed during execution.

Comment: *Suppose I wish to change the name of `user_id` to `user_identification`.* I admit that you want to do that. But I strongly doubt that it is necessary to do this, and that if it is not done, it will lead to some problems. Rather, it is renaming that will cause problems - you will not only have to change the names in the data schema, but also do the same in the client application.

Comment: Of course, you may create according updatable views which renames the columns, like ```CREATE VIEW modern_users AS SELECT user_id user_identificator, name, gender
FROM users;```, and use it instead of the original table.

Answer (score 1):

User-defined variables can substitute for scalar values (e.g. quoted strings), not identifiers.

If you want to make an SQL query using a variable for an identifier, you would have to use dynamic SQL. Typically we format a string for the SQL query in a client application, and there we can substitute a table name depending on our preference. For example in a Python f-string:

```
sql = f"""SELECT * FROM {tablename}"""
```

Or in SQL:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `", @user_id, "`");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Renaming tables or columns is often tricky in SQL databases. It's easiest if you can pause the application, execute all your renames, then make code changes in your application so it uses the new names. Then start the application (test thoroughly of course).

You don't necessarily have to change all the names in all tables at once. There's no reason — except for your own sense of consistency — that `user_id` must have the same column name in both `users` and `movie_user`. So you could do these changes one table at a time, and test after each change.

Comment: +1 That's super helpful. Thanks for taking the time to reply!